# Drupal Save in "manage fields" page is extremely slow

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-entities

I have an entity that has around 40 fields. When I try to save new fields/update exiting fields in the manage fields window, the save/post operation takes too much time (around 6 to 8 minutes). Sometimes the page is just refreshed and the newly added fields don't appear. However, I don't see errors in Drupal error log. How can I debug this problem further? Are there any optimization tips that need to be taken into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at PHP error logs?

Maybe you should increase increase your PHP memory limit.